# Tangent to integral curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation like:
$$4y'=y(x^2-4x-3)$$
and I have to find the equation to the tangent to the integral curve, which goes through a random point from the square $K =$ $\{-5≤x≤6,-6≤y≤5 \}$. I am confused by the square part. What is actually wanted here, me choosing a point that I like, or is there something more to it?

Comment: For a safe answer, consider that the point can be anywhere in the given square, and make sure to analyze if there are no "special behaviors" somewhere in it (like undefined tangent - as regards me, I don't see any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to pick a random number, a, from 0 to 1 and pick another random number, b, also from 0 to 1. Then $x_0=-5+11a$ and $y_0=-6+11b$. So point $(x_0,y_0)$ is a random point in the specified square.

A line with known slope $k_0$ and going through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by:

$$ y-y_0=k_0 (x-x_0) \text{   (1)}$$

The explicit expression of your curve is given by:

$$y(x)=C \exp\left(\frac{1}{12}(x^2-6x-9)\right)$$

To make sure that point $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the curve, we solve $C$ from

$$y_0=C \exp\left(\frac{1}{12}(x_0^2-6x_0-9)\right)$$
Since
$$k(x)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{4}y(x)(x^2-4x-3)$$

You may get the desired equation by setting $k_0=k(x_0)$ in (1).

Comment: well, apart from the $$x_0=−5+11a$$ and $$y_0=−5+11b$$ I kind of did the same thing, hope the assistant doesn't rage at me...

Comment: @MarioStoilov Good. You are on the right track. By the way, I just corrected the value for $y_0$ according to your original question. Can you double check?

Comment: yea, didn't notice that. It's ok

Comment: hmm, I actually am having a problem with the tangent. What equation do you get for it?

Comment: from your original equation

Comment: I meant the end result for the tangent

Comment: Your original equation is $4y'=4(dy/dx)=y(x^2-4x-3)$. So the tangent is $k=(dy/dx)=y(x^2-4x-3)/4$.

Comment: isn't the tangent suppose to be a line? $$y(x^2−4x−3)/4$$ is not strait

Comment: good comment. I changed the answer to specify that the slope is taken at point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @MarioStoilov I added formula $y(x)$ and made sure that point $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the curve.